# properly creating arrays of arrays in julia

Tags: arrays, julia

i would like to populate an array of arrays with integers in julia. the following works:

```
a = Array{Int64}[]
push!(a, [1,2,3])
```

but this doesn't:

```
a = Array{Array{Int64}}[]
push!(a, [1, 2, 3])
```

the error is: `` MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Int64 to an object of type Array{Int64,N} where N ``

can someone explain why? it seems like `Array{Array{Int64}}` should be the type of array whose elements are arrays containing Int64 values whereas `Array{Int64}` is an array of integers. yet `a = Array{Int64}[]` seems to initialize an array *of arrays* containing integers and not an array of integers? can someone clarify the logic here?

Comment: I believe you want append not push.

Comment: The simple explanation is that `T[]` creates an empty `Vector{T}`. So `Array{Int}[]` creates a `Vector{Array{T}}`. Be aware that you should _not_ use `Array{T}`. Always use `Vector{T}` instead, or alternatively specify the number of dimensions, as in `Array{Int, 1}`. My advice: _always_ use `Vector{T}` and `Matrix{T}` instead of `Array{T, 1}` and `Array{T, 2}`. _Never_ use `Array{T}`, it creates an abstract type.

Comment: @DNF what do you mean abstract type for array? the docs say ``Julia provides the Vector and Matrix constructor functions, but these are simply aliases for uninitialized one and two dimensional arrays`` - isn't ``Vector`` an alias for ``Array``? The default type for ``[1,2,3]`` is array.

Comment: Yes, `Vector{T}` is an alias for `Array{T, 1}` and `Matrix{T}` is an alias for `Array{T,2}`. The problem is that people _always_ forget to specify the dimensionality, writing `Array{T}` instead. This is an abstract type, because it's a union of all arrays of all dimensionalities with the element type `T`. Writing `Vector` or `Matrix` ensures that you do not forget the dimensionality, and it makes your code more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
a = Array{Int64}[]
push!(a, [1,2,3])
```

is a vector of arrays and after the operation you have a 1-element vector containing one array:

```
julia> a
1-element Array{Array{Int64,N} where N,1}:
 [1, 2, 3]

julia> a[1]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
```

While:

```
a = Array{Array{Int64}}[]
```

creates you a vector of arrays of arrays:

```
julia> a = Array{Array{Int64}}[]
0-element Array{Array{Array{Int64,N} where N,N} where N,1}
```

so you can `push!` into it arrays of arrays, e.g.:

```
julia>     push!(a, [[1,2,3]])
1-element Array{Array{Array{Int64,N} where N,N} where N,1}:
 [[1, 2, 3]]

julia> a[1]
1-element Array{Array{Int64,N} where N,1}:
 [1, 2, 3]

julia> a[1][1]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
```

Comment: thanks. could you explain how this translates into function signatures? is ``function process_array(s::Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1})`` the proper way to say the function takes an array of array of arrays of int? Why is ``1`` dimension necessary to be there explicitly and not just ``Array{Array{Array{Int64}}}}``

Comment: I hope @DNF explained why `1` appears in the above very well (and you should generally use `Vector` and `Matrix` unless you need objects of higher dimensionality). Now regarding the signatures if you write `T[]` then a function call that accepts this value should be specified as `f(::Vector{T})` (so essentially in function call you have an additional `Vector` on top of what you specify when constructing an object).